# how to test sco packets in bluetooth

Tags: fedora, alsa, bluetooth, bluez

**Issue :**  Monitor sco packets between master and slave bluetooth.

**Description of problem**. I have small in-house Bluetooth device (developed in Linux fedora OS) and is configured as slave device.

I am interested in following things:

1. Master to connect to our in-built device and establish an sco link. How would I verify link is established?
2. Master to send sco packets to slave and slave send back( loopback) the same packets to master. Absolutely no idea how to do that?

**What I did so far**:

1. Well I have configured our in-built device to slave and successfully connected to windows laptop via bluetooth.
2. I have enabled headset profile in my in-house BT device  and I can see headset icon on windows.
3. on Linux side via c++ code I have modified `/etc/asound.conf` to include mac-address of connected device( in my case windows laptop) .
   sample is shown below

   ```
   pcm.btheadset {
      type plug
      slave {
          pcm {
              type bluetooth
              device DC:A9:71:8D:2D:C6
              profile "auto"
          }
      }
   ```
4. then play the sound on my in-house BT  via command `aplay -D btheadset " path of audio_file"`

And I can successfully hear sound on my windows laptop.

So far so good.
Now when I do `hciconfig -a`

acl packets have increase but sco remain at 0

```
RX bytes:1041 acl:456 sco:0 events:36 errors:0
TX bytes:1347 acl:567 sco:0 commands:34 errors:0
```

**Will this proof that audio is working but not via sco?**

1. I have found that I don't have btsco driver or `hcid.conf` file. Do you think that could be an issue?
2. if my audio is working via sco could someone provide me an example of how to test via `hcidump`?
3. how to loop it back to master?

Comment: I did hcidump  and save the file while music was playing. I dump the  save file in wireshark and use "bthci_sco"  to filter packets and found no packets. Wondering then how does music works then?

Answer (score 0):

fter few days of struggle with Ubuntu crashing frequently finally it worked.

Below are the steps I have tried. Please take it as a reference as there is high chances that I might have forgotten to write some steps

...................................................................................................
Overview of a problem: Trying to connect Linux OS to BT headset and to establish sco link to play music

UBuntu configuration:
Kernel version : 3.0.0-32-generic
Ubuntu Verion ->11.10

Testing Device : JABRA EASY GO headset..
.............................................................................. 1) Install above version of Ubuntu . This Ubuntu version is out of support but since my in -house device use nearly same kernel version so I sticked with this version.

2) Configure apt-get sources list. Since installed version is out of support , apt-get will not work. To make it work, modify the /etc/apt/sources.list.
example->

sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
3) I would recommend to install synaptic as well to install packages and missing libraries.

4) Install following packages -->

```
 bluez-hcidump 
 bluez-utils
 libbluetooth1 
 libbluetooth1-dev
 install automake-1.7 and autoconfig
 cvs
```

5) Google it to download source code of btsco or alternatively

use following comand

cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@bluetooth-alsa.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/bluetooth-alsa login
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@bluetooth-alsa.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/bluetooth-alsa co btsco
6) NOW COMPILING AND INSTALLING

i) go to btsco directory

ii) ./bootstrap issues:
if error/ warning: macro `AM_PATH_SDL' not found in library install libbsdl1.2-dev

once bootsrap passed execute configure ii) ./configure issues :

if bluetooth/bluetooth .h missing -> install libbluetooth-dev
package requirement dbus-1>=0.36 not meet & dbus-glib not found -->install libdbus-glib-1-dev
iii) make

issues: ./libtool: line 841: X--tag=CXX: command not found and many more errors like this

To resolve that error : download libtool-1.5.24 tar ball . extract it and do configure and make . now again do configure on btsco and copy libtool executeable from libtool dir to btsco.

iv) make install v) make mainatiner-clean O/p : btsco is build successfull and you can find it in /usr/local/bin.

7) Build Kernel module

i) cd /usr/src/btsco/kernel

ii) make

issues: I assume you will get huge list of errors. open btsco.cand handle each error step by step

1 error sound/driver.h not found bla bla -> comment that in btsco.c file
2 comment #include as this is obsolete now
3) add

#include< linux/smp.h>
 #include< linux/muxtex.h>
4) DEFINE_MUTEX(os_mutex);

5) snd_assert is obsolete so replace uit by if statment example

if( bt_sco->playback == NULL) 
{

}
6) replace kill_proc( again obsolete ) by function below 9 copied from net .. tahnks to that guy) link : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/is-there-any-kill_proc-replacement-for-proprietary-linux-kernel-drivers-4175460017/

int my_kill_proc(pid_t pid, int sig) {
    int error = -ESRCH;              /* default return value */
    struct task_struct* p;
    struct task_struct* t = NULL; 
    struct pid* pspid;
    rcu_read_lock();
    p = &init_task;                  /* start at init */
    do {
        if (p->pid == pid) {         /* does the pid (not tgid) match? */
        t = p;

        break;
        }
    p = next_task(p);    /* "this isn't the task you're looking for" */
    } while (p != &init_task);   /* stop when we get back to init */
    if (t != NULL) {
        pspid = t->pids[PIDTYPE_PID].pid;
        if (pspid != NULL) error = kill_pid(pspid,sig,1);
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
    return error;
}
and then instead of kill_proc should be

my_kill_proc( bt_sco->thread_pid, SIGINT )
6) replace %d to %lu for error long int

7) replace lock_kernal to mutex_lock( &os_mutex) same for unlock

hopefully make will be successful after that

8) make install 9) depmod -e 10 0 make clean

11) modprobe snd_bt_sco

......................................

Now run btsco

a) hciconfig hci0 voice 0X0060

b) hcitool scan

get mac_addre4ss of JABRA

c) /usr/local/bin/btsco -r -v mac_addrees

if get error ?: control open (hw:1) then jabra doesnt support sco or kernel module is not loaded

d) on another terminal do -> sudo hcidump -i hci0 sco to monitor sco packets

e) once jabr connection is established run aplay -D  plughw:Headset  /home/my_home_dir/my_sample_fiile.wav